When deriving ELBO to solve variational inference problems why do we know p(z) and p(x,z) but not p(x) and p(z|x)?
I am a bit lost with the derivation of ELBO because I dont understand why some distributions are known and some are unknown.
I guess we know p(z) (the prior) because it was the last value of q(z) after the previous piece of evidence was considered?
I guess we cant use p(z|x) = p(x,z) / p(x) because we dont know p(x)?
I dont know how we can know p(x,z) but not p(x).  Surely the information in p(x) is contained in p(x,z)?  so if you know p(x,z) then you should be able to find p(x)?
any help is much appreciated.

The prior $p(z)$ as a distribution over the latent variable $z$ is chosen by the modeler and is typically a simple distribution like a MVN. Since it's defined by the modeler thus it's known. Similarly, the likelihood $p(x|z)$ is considered known as it's also usually defined by the modeler as some simple distribution like MVN, for example, see variational autoencoder. Finally since $p(x,z)=p(x|z)p(z)$, your title description is right that $p(x,z)$ is also known.
However, the evidence $p(x)$ is often intractable thus considered unknown. The root cause is the existence of the latent/missing variable $z$ as discussed in my recent answer for another post. Basically $p(x)=\int _{z}p({x,z})\,dz$ requires integrating over the usually high-dimensional continuous latent space $z$ which is often intractable. And further it's obvious that the posterior $p(z|x)$ is also unknown. So ELBO is a way to sidestep the need to directly compute $p(x)$ by instead optimizing a lower bound on $\log p(x)$ via the variational posterior $q(z|x)$

You could say there are two interpretations of "know" here: $p(x)$ is determined by information we have, but it's not easily computable from information we have.  A comparable question is whether knowing a matrix $A$ means we know $A^{-1}$: it's determined by $A$ but there might be a lot of work in computing it.

@ThomasLumley thx for your helpful feedback. Indeed here OP's 'known' is somewhat vague, I would say $p(x)$ is computable in the sense of theoretic Turing computability but intractable in the sense of numerical inaccuracy under practical complexity. So unknown just means intractability essentially.

thank you very much for your comments.  I think one problem that I have is that in the VAE there are two x's (?)  so when we write p(x|z) the x here is the output of the decoder and when we write p(z|x) the x here is the input of the encoder.  can you tell me if that is right please?  so when we write p(x) is it the input of the encoder or the output of the decoder that the x refers to?  p(x) here is the probability that the data have pixel values = x ?  thanks for your help

$p(x)$ here is the same probability that the data have pixel values = $x$, and you're right that in $p(x∣z)$ here $x$ refers to the reconstructed output of the decoder and in $p(z|x)$ the original $x$ here is the input of the encoder.

thanks very much again, its very kind of you to help.  Like Columbo I have just one more question:  does the x in p(x) refer to the input of the encoder or the output of the decoder?  I assume output of the decoder?

This x is the original input of the encoder, not the generatively reconstructed output of decoder. Hope it now completely clarifies.
